# Automatically surround generated code with #region when implementing interfaces at Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know that in Visual Studio 2013 and below there is an option to turn on/off automatic surrounding of generated code with `#region` at `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced> Surround generated code with #region`, but that option seems to be removed in Visual Studio 2015...

Is there a way to turn this back on?

Comment: You can write that feature with Roslyn.

Comment: This is most likely a bug as the setting is still described in the [property page's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165334.aspx).

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and can confirm this has not yet been resolved. Has anyone reported this to Microsoft yet?

Comment: Created MS Connect issue here (please vote): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3110726

Comment: Seems to be still gone in VS2017...

Comment: Can't find it under Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I think this should be possible with using some Custom Template right?? Or maybe a custom analyzer that will be triggered on Interface implementation?? Can someone try creating one of those as I am not very much familiar with those?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into [CodeMaid](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) at the Visual Studio Gallery. 
According to the description:

> Reorganize the layout of members in a C# file to
>   follow Microsoft’s StyleCop convention, or your own preferences.
>   Automatically generate regions to match. Run on demand or
>   automatically during cleanup.

From what I can tell, this may give you the feature to want.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option (that i've found) to do this when it implement a interface, it just puts regions between constructors, fields, etc

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend delving into ReSharper templates. It allows you to specify whatever you would like in your template as well as creating a autocomplete as well.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Templates__Index.html