# Force Visual Studio to insert interface implementation code at the bottom

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation

I am wondering if there is any way to force visual studio to insert the auto-generated code at the bottom instead of "intelligently" inserting each method body into the existing code in alphabetical order? It just gets a little annoying when I have to find every single method.

Comment: I believe putting generated method stubs at the bottom is the default behaviour. Try resetting your settings.

Comment: @GSerg, thanks for the suggestion, I just tried, but I'm afraid it's still behaving the same. I'm using VS2015 Community by the way. and it's C# i'm coding in.

Comment: Apparently [there is a problem with this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31551803/11683) in VS 2015.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. at least i now know it's not just me having the same wonder.